# How to create a transient that persists the data for the whole duration of the expiration, even when object cache is enabled?

Tags: cache, transient

Anyone recommends an alternative to `set_transient` that persists the data for the whole duration of the expiration even when object cache is enabled?

Example:

- List item
- Set a long-duration transient `set_transient('foo', 'bar', WEEK_IN_SECONDS);`
- Site is using object cache, so this is saved in
  memory
- I don't know internals of Redis, but memory cache is cleared
  for some reason:

  - Redis [rotates](https://redis.io/docs/reference/eviction/) cache based on the [eviction policy](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/databases/memory-performance/eviction-policy/)
  - Server reboots
  - O.S-level memory management frees up memory
  - etc?

Now that transient expired before 1 week.

In a scenario such as this, how can I create a value that is able to persist for a longer period?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually used a combination of `update_option` and WP Cron:

```
// Create the option.
update_option('foo', 'bar', false);

/**
* Schedule it to be deleted one week from now.
* 
* @param int Expiration timestamp
* @param string Hook that will be invoked
* @param string Params to send to the hook callback
*/
wp_schedule_single_event( time() + WEEK_IN_SECONDS, 'expire_option', [ 'foo' ] );

// Register the hook.
add_action( 'expire_option', 'expire_option_callback', 10, 1 );

// This will be called by WP Cron when we want to "expire" the option, one week after its creation.
function expire_option_callback( $option_name ) {
  delete_option( $option_name );
}
```

The only drawback is that the option won't be expired if WP Cron is not working in the site. If this is unnaceptable, you'll need a more robust solution mimicking how transients are saved and expired in the DB.

Comment: +1, transients by definition are not reliable storage. As for cron, you can trust it working otherwise some other things will not work as well. The other alternative is to store a time stamp as part of the option, like it is actually done for transients.